# Grunt Serve:Dist not creating folder in views partials

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs

I have created folder within folder for Views like this :-

```
views - partials - controls - results
```

There are multiple .html pages in `results` folder.

All is working fine locally. But when i do `grunt serve:dist`, i got error :-

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

When i look in `dist` folder there are no folders created for `controls - results`.

What do i need to change in `grunt.js` files so that this folders get created.

Comment: Did you run the command grunt dist before to generate the dist folder?

Comment: I just ran the command `grunt serve:dist`

Comment: Than try with `grunt dist` first, then once it's completed run `grun serve:dist`

Comment: when i go for `grunt dist` get error :- `warning: Task "dist" not found. Used --force, continuing.`

Comment: How did you setup your grunt file? Which tasks do you have available?